# Android Open MainActivity after click back button in Notification Activity

Tags: android

I am developing one application, which will show a list of Card View inside a Recycler view in MainActivity. While clicking the Card view it will launch different activity. The flow is 
SplashScreenActivity -> MainActivity(Recycler View) -> DetailsActivity
The flow is working fine if we launch the application by clicking app icon.

As part of this app, I am sending FCM notifications to the app. Whenever notification is received DetailsActivity will be launched, during that time MainActivity will not be in the stack. I am staring the MainActivity whenever backbutton of Details Activity is being pressed.If DetailsActivity is not called from Notification then I am not calling MainActivity again.

Below is the code snippet I have done to handle back button in Details Activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isFromNotification) {
        System.out.println("Start from Notification");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(intent);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Start from Normal Mode");
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

I have two issues here.

i) When FCM is received Notification is viewed in DetailsActivity. After pressing the back button MainActivity is launched and DetailsActivity is not killed. After Pressing the back button from MaainActivity again Details Activity is launched.

ii) Whenever MainActivity is launched by after receiving notification (By Clicking back button of Details Activity), recyclerview elements are not clickable.

I tried my best to explain the issue, your help is really appreciated !!!

Comment: for first issue you can just add a finish(); after starting the mainactivity in your if condition. It will kill the detailsActivity on backpressed. For second issue, we might need more details on code or xml file to look into.

Comment: added finish() method,once i presses the back button in MainActivity the application is available in the application tray (where you can find list of runnning / minimized apps) once I click my application it is launching the Details Activity.

Comment: For the second issue I have a fragment on top of MainActivity. That fragment is holding the recycler view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PendingIntent` you include in the notification shown by your FCM message can describe a backstack with your MainActivity below your DetailsActivity.

```java
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class));
PendingIntent notificationIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```